# Elements appear on click but height of page stays the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following code makes the `#row-` elements display when a label in `#row-product_id_page-0-0` is clicked:

```
 $('#row-product_id_page-0-0 label').click(function() {
    var str = $(this).find('.am-product-title').text()
    var levelText = str.substring(0, 15)

    $('#row-html2-0, #row-html3-0, #row-html4-0').show()    
    $('#row-qfauto-1, #row-qfauto-2, #row-email-0, #row-pass-0').show()    
    $('#row-pass-confirm, #row-buttons').show()    

    $('#row-html3-0 span').text(levelText)

  })
```

The DOM before clicking a label:

[image]

After clicking a label:

[image]

The strange thing is, the element appear but the height of the page stays the same:

Before clicking:

[image]

After clicking:

[image]

As if that wasn't weird enough things become okay if I open the Chrome inspector (the same problem happens in Firefox):

[image]

I'm baffled. What could be the problem?

Live site: http://clo2015.chineselearnonline.com/amember/signup/landing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This trick will work:

```
$('#row-product_id_page-0-0 label').click(function() { 
    $(window).resize(); 
});
```

This also shows the reason why when you open the inspector, the newly created element will render in the correct way, simply because when you open the inspector, the browser will trigger a window resize event. You may try to drag the window to resize it a little bit, and you will see the same effect.

I didn't dig into your javascript code, but you may check what handlers do you register in window.resize event. Possibly the answer is there.

## Notes:

I think [Albert Xing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1229971/albert-xing) is right here:

> You have dynamically set the height of a `<div role="main">` inside of
> `.container`. This div is overflowing.

Answer (score 1):

You have dynamically set the height of a `<div role="main">` inside of `.container`. This `div` is overflowing.

When you open Dev Tools, the window resizes which recomputes the height of the `div`.

You may want to

1. call `$(window).resize()` when an option is selected (this is more of a workaround than a fix)
2. find another way to handle layout without dynamically setting the height of the container